# VB.NET / First row missing when writing to a CSV file

Tags: vb.net, csv

Wrote a program that writes name, postcode, device type, damage type to a CSV file and for some reason it misses the first row.

Thanks

```
Sub fileWriting(ByVal file As String, ByVal name As String, ByVal postcode As String, ByVal dmgType As String, ByVal devType As String) ' writing to files function
        Dim ObjStreamWriter As StreamWriter
        ObjStreamWriter = New StreamWriter(file, True)


        ObjStreamWriter.Write(name & ",")
        ObjStreamWriter.Write(postcode & ",")
        ObjStreamWriter.Write(dmgType & ",")
        ObjStreamWriter.WriteLine(devType)

        ObjStreamWriter.Close()

    End Sub
```

[image]

Comment: Where is the writing of multiple lines here?

Comment: Well this is just a smaller part of the code but if I want to add a user I just run the program instead of it being looped

Comment: Please read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and update your question appropriately. It doesn't need to be the code for your actual project. It needs to be the least code possible to demonstrate the actual issue you're asking about. If you have to create a new project to isolate the functionality then do that and, in fact, you already should have for your own testing.

Comment: You could replace the entire body of that method with a single line of code: `File.AppendAllText(file, $"{name},{postcode},{dmgType},{devType}{Environment.NewLine}")`.

Comment: Think your issue here might be more around how and where you're calling this method rather than the method itself.  Are you able to update your question with that?

Answer (score 0):

One point on the code above:

```
ObjStreamWriter = New StreamWriter(file, True)
```

will append to an existing file, if the file already exists.  Therefore the text you're appending may exist further down in the file depending how much you've already written.

Additionally, `StreamWriter` implements `IDisposable` so the preferred method of implementation is to instantiate it in a `Using` block, if you're immediately closing the object.

```
Using ObjStreamWriter = New StreamWriter(file, True)
    ObjStreamWriter.Write(name & ",")
    ObjStreamWriter.Write(postcode & ",")
    ObjStreamWriter.Write(dmgType & ",")
    ObjStreamWriter.WriteLine(devType)
End Using
```

I'm not sure if these will fix your issue as there's insufficient code to really determine that, but if you're having issues with text not flushing, this ensures that you're automatically doing everything needed to properly close the file.  Normally that'd be text missing from the end of the file, not the start, but it might help.